# Is it appropriate to cite a piece of academic work when the author has been charged with child pornography?

Tags: publications, citations, thesis, authorship

It has recently come to my attention that a renowned scholar in my field whose academic journals have been highly influential in my area of research has recently been charged with child pornography. Is it possible to separate the scholar from their work? And will my thesis research, in turn, be judged for referencing the work?

Comment: Related: [How does it affect the treatment of a mathematician's results, if that mathematician was a Nazi?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/84829/how-does-it-affect-the-treatment-of-a-mathematicians-results-if-that-mathemati)

Comment: Also related: [How to deal with sources whose authors I don't have good relationship with?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/112420/14341)

Comment: Sounds like an ad hominem fallacy

Comment: Citation is not the same as "liking".  If you cite "Mein Kempf" then you should credit Hitler as the author - regardless of your position on the Holocaust.  You can cite Hitler in a disapproving way.

Comment: If, however, the work is unrelated to the misconduct, I would not cite the author in a "disapprovong way", but just neutral without any comment.

Comment: Just as "citation" is not the same as "liking," "charged" is not the same as "convicted."

Comment: @WayneConrad indeed, it is possible to even approve and "like" the convicted.  Sometimes the people are right and the law is wrong.  We are learning that the Trump administration is criminally charging people who provide food and water to migrants.  Are we to stop citing the scholar criminals among them?  To stay on topic, the multiple concepts of "citation" and "conviction" are completely uncorrelated.

Comment: I think the title of this question is poorly matched with the content. "Arrested" can have a huge range of reasons that could be anywhere from highly negative to neutral to positive regarding the author's character. The key point is not "has been arrested" but "has been [credibly?] charged with [child pornography/sexual abuse of children/???]".

Comment: Leonardo Da Vinci butchered pigs alive, and is still very famous for his influence in art.

Comment: In addition to the other points, in the US people are still entitled to be considered innocent until proven guilty.

Comment: Another related issue: [If someone conducts unethical research unbeknownst to anybody, but produces positive results, what would happen to the research once discovered?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/31116/22733)

Comment: What about people who cite Adolf Hitler's book? And Theodore Kaczynski is a serial murderer serving eight consecutive life sentences, and before his criminal career began, he published a novel proof of Wedderburn's theorem (which states that all finite division rings are commutative). I don't think it would have occurred to me to avoid citing that if the occasion arose, on the grounds of its author's crimes.

Answer (score 66):

Of course it is appropriate. Why not? They did relevant work, so you have to cite them. With citing, you do your duty -- you are in no way saying you "like" the cited persons.

Of course, I am assuming that their research is sound and is not somehow influenced by the child pornography. It was a different case if there were problems with the research.

On the other hand, not citing them could get you into big (or small) trouble.

Answer (score 26):

I think that in almost every field you can separate the work from the person who did it. Many people in the history of science and mathematics, at least, have turned out to have "feet of clay." You aren't tainted because you use someone's work.

The only exception I can think of is if the charge of misconduct is somehow related to the research - unlikely.

The Unabomber was a prize-winning mathematician before he turned evil. His mathematical work doesn't disappear from history.

Comment: If only every scientific organization was reasonable enough to separate the work from the person... "[In response to his most recent statements, which effectively reverse the written apology and retraction Dr. Watson made in 2007, the Laboratory has taken additional steps, including revoking his honorary titles of Chancellor Emeritus, Oliver R. Grace Professor Emeritus, and Honorary Trustee.](https://www.cshl.edu/statement-by-cold-spring-harbor-laboratory-addressing-remarks-by-dr-james-d-watson-in-american-masters-decoding-watson/)"

Comment: @JonathanReez That doesn't seem relevant to me. If a journal in which Watson had published decided to retract his paper(s) because of his recent statements, then it would be very topical, but the article you linked is talking about his titles, which is different.

Comment: "before he turned evil". Are you implying that being a prize-winning mathematician precludes you from being evil?

Comment: @DavidZ if the title was earned fairly, no future actions should lead to losing that title. At least not actions outside of academia.

Comment: @JonathanReez ok, that is an interesting and very irrelevant point. You could ask a separate question about that if you like ("should titles be revoked for crimes/etc?"), I'd be interested in reading about it. But titles being revoked doesn't really have anything to do with the actual research or the paper being revoked.

Comment: @Sparhawk I don't see that implication. I think buffy is saying that before acting, he was just disturbed or something. It's only when he ACTED that you would call him evil.

Comment: @JonathanReez specifically, the titles they revoked are *honorary* titles. Nobody revoked his doctorate, and the statement you linked explicitly acknowledges the significance of Dr Watson's previous work...

Comment: @user94036 I just found the wording slightly odd.

Comment: @Sparhawk ok, yeah, I get that. I agree. I don't really like using terms like good and evil, because I don't believe in concrete binaries like that. I would have said "before he committed his crimes" or something. I just thought I would clarify what I THOUGHT buffy meant (but I could totally be wrong).

Answer (score 3):

I agree completely with guest2's answer. I'll add this: **The author has only been *charged*. He/She hasn't been *convicted*.**

Presumption of innocence - i.e. the idea that people are innocent until proven guilty - is one of the most sacred principles of the criminal justice system. Even if someone disapproves of you citing a child pornographer, they can't really fault you for doing so before the author is convicted.

Comment: While this is a good point (and it's important to point out that it is not the OP's role to act as a judge), note that the original question said they were "arrested" and somebody different then the OP changed this to "charged".

Comment: @guest2 "Arrested" isn't "convicted" either, too.

Comment: Isn't "proven guilty in the eyes of the law" a prerequisite for "being arrested" in most countries?

Comment: @guest2 no, you can be arrested without being charged, let alone found guilty - see e.g. https://www.legalmomentum.org/sites/default/files/reports/answeringcrquestions.pdf question 1.

Comment: maybe you're thinking of "probable cause", which I believe in the US is a requirement both for being arrested and for being charged with a crime.

Comment: Okay ,sorry! I thought "arrested" would mean "being in prison after a trial". Not a native English speaker.

Answer (score 1):

To add another perspective to this, you even knowing of this author’s (alleged) crimes is a great coincidence:

- A considerable amount of criminals is never caught.
  In particular for ownership of child pornography, I would expect the dark figures to be so high that I have likely cited somebody guilty of it.
- In many countries, e.g., Germany, privacy laws or at least codices of press, police, etc. forbid publishing the name of a criminal for protection of their rights, allowing rehabilitation, etc.
  Names are usually made public only if the person in question is in public spotlight anyway (e.g., in [this case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sebastian_Edathy) of a member of parliament) or the case itself is of extraordinary public or historic interest (such as [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Germanwings_Flight_9525), and even there, it took a while).
  So, you probably only know about the crimes of the author in question because they were in a country with another attitude to privacy, were considered in the public spotlight anyway, or information leaked out somehow.
- You either had to investigate this author or this was a widely available knowledge in your field, which is also something you cannot assume to happen in every case – at least I do not investigate whether there is some public criminal track record of every person I cite.

So, what makes that specific author different from authors whose crimes you never get to know?

And even if we presume that something is different, what should the scientific community do about it?
Reiterate the author’s entire work and publish it again, so it can be cited?
Is every convicted criminal’s work free game for plagiarism?
(This becomes particularly absurd in fields like pure math, where a paper can be fully self-contained.)

The only exception from all of this I can see is if the author’s research can be expected to be biased due to pedophilia.
But then it’s upon the scientific community or the respective journals to judge this and retract or annotate the respective publications.

Answer (score -10):

Others calling this an "ad hominem fallacy" or saying you must "separate the scholar from their work" are wrong. In a system where citation is the currency that fuels careers, you can't separate them; any resolution of this dilemma must acknowledge and attempt to mitigate the fact that the author cited does usually benefit from citations. This is particularly true in cases where the author is still alive and still has a career, but in the case of hateful ideologies (e.g. Nazi works), there is also the aspect of citation benefiting the ideology that lives on past the author.

Now, how do you do that? It's hard, and academia doesn't have good solutions right now. Fixing the whole academic publishing system and citation economy is related, but not really something you can wait on. From an academic integrity standpoing, you do have an obligation to accurately cite work you used, were influenced by, or built on. But if this person is a "renowned scholar" and "highly influential" in his area of research, there's also a good chance that he's going to get off with a slap on the wrist, partly due to the justice system and academic community considering him "too big to fail" or considering the "value of his work" too important to jeopardize by ostracizing him.

Sadly, I don't have any good answers for how to fix this or even avoid being complicit in it. But I do think it's worth saying that the people who are telling you it's not an issue are morally bankrupt.

On a related note, the Unabomber was [once cited with a footnote](https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/rlamc/better_known_for_other_work/) "Better known for other work."

Comment: Sorry, but THE ACADEMIC COMMUNITY IS NOT RESPONSIBLE FOR THE IDIOTIC CITATION-AS-CURRENCY SITUATION (if anything, we are working hard to fix it), so there is no reason why we should throw our backs out just to work around it. RTs are not endorsements; citations are not applause.

Comment: You might want to add to your answer WHY exactly people calling this „ad hominem“ are wrong, and WHY one can not (in opposite to: should not) separate scholar and work.

Comment: "But I do think it's worth saying that the people who are telling you it's not an issue are morally bankrupt."

Disagreeing with you on moral issues doesn't mean other people are morally bankrupt, and it is a bad idea to jump from a disagreement on a moral or ethical issue  to making such conclusions about a lack of morality in others.

Comment: @darijgrinberg: You don't get to decide if they're endorsements or applause; the system/the market does, and it's decided that they are.

Comment: @JoshuaZ: Telling someone who's conscience is telling them there is a real moral dilemma here that it's not real and they can just ignore it is what I call "moral bankruptcy". Whether or what you should do about it is a valid question, but dismissing the OP's concern is not.

Comment: @R..: You don't get to decide if someone is morally bankrupt either :P

Comment: @R.. First of all, none of the replies asserted that it isn't "real" - they made specific arguments about why it shouldn't be a concern. Second, if someone does have a moral concern and one doesn't think it is substantial, are you arguing that one shouldn't tell them that when they are specifically asking about what is or not appropriate?

Comment: Re "in the case of hateful ideologies", hateful to whom?  There are all sorts of ideologies I personally dislike, from communism to fundamentalist religion to sports fandom.  Should my opinion of these relieve me of the obligation to cite relevant work?

Comment: @darijgrinberg I'd love to know exactly how the academic community is not responsible for citations being highly valued within the academic community.

Comment: @ElizabethHenning: Administration and administrative pressure, as well as publishers' pushing of citation-based ratings is. You may count them into the academic community, in which case we are misreading each other's language.

Comment: @darijgrinberg So you're saying that citations play no part in your own evaluation of someone's work? Or how strong they are as a job candidate?

Comment: I have not had the occasion to evaluate job candidates, but citations of their papers would not play a significant part in my evaluation on their work. The only cases where I see them possibly be useful is when you are evaluating someone outside of your subfield; however your vote doesn't count for much in that cases (I would recluse myself from mathematically evaluating an analyst, for example). Personal qualities, as far as anything is known about them, figure separately in an evaluation; there is little chance that a proven(!) child abuser (the OP isn't great at distinguishing arrest ...

Comment: ... from conviction) would get through a hiring process at a job that involves teaching anyway.

Comment: "Currency" is only useful if you're allowed to open a bank account. And no, citing Bieberbach for his work in complex analysis and citing Kneser for his development of normal surface theory do _not_ give credence or support to their virulent anti-Semitism.

Comment: In mathematics, are we supposed to completely abandon the study of the dynamics of complex variables, because anything we do in that field would be building on the work of [Ludwig Bieberbach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ludwig_Bieberbach), who was a virulently anti-semitic Nazi? Of course not. Hopefully, the academic system or the courts will punish the offending scientist, while his work remains available to future science.

Comment: @PeterShor: No, and I told readers I don't have any good answer for how to fix it. My answer is that there is a real moral issue here, one of what is morally appropriate, and that we as individuals and communities should be seeking ways to mitigate the harm of giving prestige and attention to individuals (and in some cases ideologies) who will use that to harm others and escape consequences for that harm.

Comment: @JeffE The present situation doesn't involve dead Nazis, it involves someone who has very recently been charged with a repulsive crime. And the issue isn't endorsement of child pornography, it's not wanting to treat a child pornographer as a colleague. A lot of the point of #metoostem is *stop looking the other way when scumbags do "good work" and consider how much other damage they might be doing.*

Comment: @ElizabethHenning I agree. I have been meaning to write an answer here including something about the differences it makes when the person is still an active academic, but I have not been able to formulate anything properly. I still agree with the general answers though that one cannot avoid citing the person, when it comes to providing an accurate account of where ideas originated. But for example the possibility of meeting this person at a conference is something that might require preparation.

Comment: I think it's worth having a conversation about whether academic citation protocols should evolve to admit citing that an idea was known from past work by others, without citing the particular work or authors, when the authors of the paper making the citation have consciously chosen not to do so. A community where you have to accept and credit people who have done and continue to do awful things is inherently toxic and exclusive of people who can't do so either because of their conscience or their own need for personal safety (including against reliving similar trauma) from such people.

Comment: @ElizabethHenning The answer explicitly referenced Nazis.  And of course we don't want child pornographers as colleagues; that's why we fire them and throw them in prison. (Hence my comment about bank accounts.) Not citing their work is not just an inappropriate response because it distorts history, but because it's _insufficient_.